# Does GCC STL have a trait that gets the primitive type from typedef aliases?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, typedef, type-traits

I can't find a metafunction which returns the primitive type from its typedef aliases, like in that possible example:

```
typedef int ivar;
typedef ivar signIvar;

...
// true
std::cout << std::is_same< int, std::get_primitive<signIvar>::type >::value;
```

It may exist, but I cannot find it. Implementation is possible in principle, but I can only make it expensive for compile time.

Comment: Why does the question say gcc stl?

Comment: I mean STL implementation for GCC

Comment: Yes, I understand, but why are you specifying that? The gcc stl implementation is supposed to provide what the standard says.

Comment: IMHO, non-standard extensions are possible, like in clibs.

Comment: The C++ standard library and STL are different things. STL has gone long ago. Read STL tag description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is conceptually no such thing as "get primitive type from its typedef alias".

An alias of a type is simply a name for the same type. As such, you can do:

```
std::cout << std::is_same_v<int, signIvar>; // output: 1
```

Comment: The problem is in type casting, i make the bunch of explicit template specialization. And compiler cannot match the original type and its alias for instantiation.

Comment: Then please show that problem in the question with a [mre]

Comment: @HolyFoxManDude Quite on the contrary, the compiler is not able to avoid matching a type and its alias. `some_template<int>` and `some_template<signIvar>` are the same instantiation of the template.

Comment: @eerorika Yes. Most likely the problem is that I was checking a fixed type (int32_t) with a regular one. It's not quite right outside x86, therefore, the conversion needs to be explicit.